# returning a value based on the minimum value from another column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, select, min

I am looking to do this:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM MyTable WHERE IsAlive = 1 AND MIN(ID)
```

I am looking to get [Name] for a person in MyTable that has the lowest ID number and I think I am going crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MIN` aggregate function is not going to return a `boolean` value. It's going to return the `MIN` of that field in that result set. Just order it properly and grab the `TOP 1`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Name] FROM MyTable WHERE IsAlive = 1 ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: @user1911612, I'm glad I could be of assistance!